# getch() returns 2 characters

Tags: c++, ncurses

Im trying to get a character from the user using getch. However it returns 2 same characters.

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    char input = getch();
    printw("%c",input);
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

does anyone know a fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type character in terminal it gets echoed back. What you see is echoed character and the result of `printw()`.

As you are using ncurses, you can easly disable echoing, by calling function `noecho()`.

Common practice is defining own function initializing curses, e.g.:

```c
void init_curses()
    if (!initscr()) {
        exit(1);
    }
    noecho();
}
```

Comment: i just realized too just now

Answer (score 0):

You get two characters because initially the input is in *buffered* mode.  The second character would be a newline.

Referring to the [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization), which says

> To get character-at-a-time input  without  echoing  (most  interactive,
> screen  oriented  programs want this), the following sequence should be
> used:
>
> `initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();`

your example was probably intended to be like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak(); // puts the terminal into unbuffered mode
    int input = getch();
    printw("%c",input);
    getch();  // actually needed for a different reason...
    endwin();
}
```

The manual page for [cbreak](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak) explains

> Normally, the tty driver buffers typed characters until  a  newline  or
> carriage  return  is typed.  The **`cbreak`** routine disables line buffering
> and erase/kill character-processing (interrupt and flow control characters  are  unaffected), making characters typed by the user immediately
> available to the program.  The **`nocbreak`** routine returns the terminal to
> normal (cooked) mode.